# Instantiating IOptions<> in xunit

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, xunit, xunit.net, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to write an xunit test for a class (in a .net Core project) that looks something like:

```cs
public Class FoodStore:IFoodStore
{
    FoodList foodItems;

    public FoodStore(IOptions<FoodList> foodItems)
    {
        this.foodItems = foodItems;
    }

    public bool IsFoodItemPresentInList(string foodItemId)
    {
        //Logic to search from Food List
    }
}`
```

Note: `FoodList` is actually a json file, containing data, that is loaded and configured in the Startup class.

How can I write an xunit test with appropriate dependency injection to test the `IsFoodItemPresentInList` method ?

Comment: [AutoFixture](https://github.com/autofixture) productises this sort of automagically wiring up the arrange phase of your tests very well [not 100% sure on whether it supports the specific version of .NET Core you are using]. @metalheart is correct that xunit itself does not do this sort of thing - while v2 does allow test collections with shared fixtures, it would be quite far off idiomatic usage to abuse that in the way you propose

Answer (score 13):

You can create an instance of `IOptions<FoodList>` using the `Options.Create` method:

```
var foodListOptions = Options.Create(new FoodList());
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use `OptionsWrapper<T>` class to fake your configuration. Then you can pass in this object to your class that you want to test. That way you don't have to use DI or read the real configuration.

Something like this:

```
var myConfiguration = new OptionsWrapper<MyConfiguration>(new MyConfiguration
            {
                SomeConfig = "SomeValue"
            });
var yourClass = new YourClass(myConfiguration);
```

Answer (score 7):

I have encountered a similar problem (using xUnit), after some struggle, I worked it out.

The answer is so late, but should be helpful for others.

---

For your Question:

```
public Class FoodStoreTest
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot _configuration;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public FoodStoreTest(){
            // read Json
            var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            _configuration = configBuilder.Build();

            // SetUp DI
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddOptions(); // this statement is required if you wanna use IOption Pattern.

            services.Configure<YuntongxunOptions>(_configuration.GetSection("yuntongxun"));
            _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetFootItemOption()
    {
         IOption<FoodList> optionAccessor = _serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<FoodList>>();
         FoodList footListOptions = optionAccessor.value;
         Assert.NotNull(footListOptions)
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

Also, you should copy "appSettings.json" to your project root folder.

Comment: can you help me?
my question i posted today have something similar please check and update me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928678/how-to-pass-service-config-to-the-xunit-project-test-controller

Answer (score 3):

In a unit test, you typically don't use Dependency Injection, since it's you who controls the creation of the tested object.

To supply a suitable object that implements `IOptions<FoodList>` you can implement a fake class with the desired behavior yourself, or use some mocking framework to configure the instance on the fly, for example [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/).

Comment: Actually, it can be very handy to use a container serving a mix of SUTs and mocks/stubs in tests provided you have handy helper methods to set things up. Take a look at this example I built: https://github.com/uWebshop/uWebshop-Releases/blob/master/Tests/uWebshop.Test/Services/PaymentProviderServiceTests.cs

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the other answers, in your test class you can create an options instance just for testing.

You can do it like this;

```
public class FakeFoodList : IOptions<FoodList>
{
    public FoodList Value
    {
        get
        {
            return new FoodList(); // TODO: Add your settings for test here.
        }
    }
}
```

And then call it like this;

```
var foodOptions = new FakeFoodList();
var foodStore = new FoodStore(foodOptions);

var response = foodStore.Act();

Assert.Equal("whatever", response);
```