# How to pass service config to the Xunit project Test controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit, fixtures, xunit.net

I have below setup currently.

Startup Class  : **Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<AzureStorageConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureStorageConfig"));
        services.AddTransient<IAzureService, AzureService>();
    }
    //other config settings ...
}
```

Class: **AzureStorageConfig**

```
//store the azure account details etc...
public class AzureStorageConfig
{ 
    public string AzureURL { get; set; } 
    public string StorageConnectionString { get; set; } 
    public string AccountName { get; set; } 
}
```

Interface class: **IAzureService**

```
public interface IAzureService
{
    Task<string> UploadFileAsync(AzureStorageConfig _storageConfig, string filename);
    Task<string> DeleteFile(AzureStorageConfig _storageConfig, string filename);
}
```

Azure class : **AzureService** that use by interface above

```
public class AzureService : IAzureService, IDisposable
{
    // Here implemented above service methods..
    public Task<string> UploadFileAsync(AzureStorageConfig _storageConfig, string filename)
    {
        //...
    }

    Task<string> DeleteFile(AzureStorageConfig _storageConfig, string filename)
    {
        //...
    }    
}
```

Image controller: **ImageController.cs**

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Images")]
public class ImagesController : Controller
{
    #region Private properties
    private readonly ApiDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private AzureStorageConfig _storageConfig;
    public readonly IAzureService _azureService;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public ImagesController(ApiDbContext context, IMapper mapper, IOptions<AzureStorageConfig> storageConfig, IAzureService azureService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _storageConfig =  storageConfig.Value;
        _azureService = azureService;
    }

    // other POST and Delete methods written
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostImage(Guid Id, [FromForm] ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {
        // here used   _storageConfig objects to use account key and names...         
    }
}
```

Main issue in below class ( TEST Library ) with xunit

Class: **ImageControllerTest**

```
[Collection("TestDb")] 
public class ImageControllerTest : IClassFixture<InitializeAutoMap>
{
    private ImagesController _controller;
    private DatabaseFixture _fixture; 
    private InitializeAutoMap _initialize;

    public ImageControllerTest(DatabaseFixture fixture, InitializeAutoMap initialize)
    {
        this._fixture = fixture; 
        this._initialize = initialize;

        // How to pass service object and StorageConfig to the main 
        //ImageController from this TestController for testing.
        _controller = new ImagesController(_context, 
            _initialize.InstanceMapper,
            /*<here I want to pass storageConfig object>*/,
            /*<here I want to pass service object>*/
        ); 
    }

    // other [Fact] testing done.
    // other codes..
}
```

How to it will possible to get injected to Xunit ImageControllerTest constructor.

- **storageConfig** class object and
- **IAzureService** object 
  into the ImageController from Xunit ImageControllerTest method.?

Share me if you have idea or solutions.

Comment: You could just mock them up and inject them into the SUT

Comment: If you want to unit test your `ImagesController`, you should pass mocks you actually have control over. Otherwise you are doing integration tests and for that you can [use the TestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing) to do actual tests against your web application.

Comment: doing UNit test with controller actions..

Comment: @Nkosi we have not used mock , want to inject into ImageControllerTest. used fixture you seen my initial startup and imagecontroller that working fine. but for Test ( xunit ) its getting issue how to pass it?

Comment: @AbhishekB. This now appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve? Give examples of the tests to be run. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: @Nkosi want to pass the configuration value and service object to the imgeController.. i can share the screen if you can look. can i?

Comment: see https://prnt.sc/hqurzc