# .Net Core Moq: An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, xunit.net

Using .net core xunit and moq.

While writing my test case, I am getting the error"

```
An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments
```

The error is on line:

```
var moqDb = new Mock<IDynamoDbClientInitialization>();
moqDb
 .Setup(_ => _.GetContext().ScanAsync<MyModel>
 (It.IsAny<List<ScanCondition>>(), AWSHelperMethods.GetDynamoDbOperationConfig(dynamoDbTable)).GetRemainingAsync())
.ReturnsAsync(data);
```

For full code for this one can refer the post at:
    [.Net core testing with Xunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879141/net-core-testing-with-xunit)

Could anyone help resolving my error here.

This post is for resolving the error I am getting, not asking for writing the unit case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net core testing with Xunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879141/net-core-testing-with-xunit)

Comment: Please keep Stackoverflow DRY. :-)

Comment: Its not duplicate. That above post I started to ask how to write a unit test. This post is for a error I am getting in test. How can they be same post?

Comment: you reference the same error in both questions.  Other Post: "Above I am getting the error as: An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments", also, the other post has an answer, which answers your question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moqDb is intance of Mock:

```
moqDb
 .Setup(_ => _.GetContext().ScanAsync<MyModel>
```

In this part of the code you trying to "call" a method ScanAsync on not already set up GetContext(). To solve this you have to Setup return value for GetContext() before you tried to Setup ScanAsync()

Comment: Sorry I am new to all these unit test. Could you let me know how to set it properly. I thought I already did when I declared  var moqDb = new Mock<IDynamoDbClientInitialization>();

Comment: Thanks. Just to give you a little info. All I am trying to do is writing test case for my api which has about 3-4 endpoints. And wanted to know how can I write a test case for that. I can bypass dynamo db mocking and just test other parts if that is in issue. All I want is one complete test so that I can write and apply the same for my other endpoints as well. Thanks for looking into.