# Unit testing with xunit that involves dynamo db

Tags: unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb, moq, xunit, xunit.net

I have a .net core api project where I am connecting to dynamo db as my database.
I also have few endpoints for getting data, saving data and deleting data from dynamo db. Now I wanted to write unit test cases for those endpoints.
Unit testing that I am able to get correct data, data correctly saves to dynamo db, data correctly gets deleted from dynamo db.

To get started with this, I came across the following post at stackoverflow and I have a similar setup already:
[.Net core testing with Xunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879141/net-core-testing-with-xunit)

I have a few questions based on the accepted answer in the above post:

The user in the above post is using MOQ to moq up data and pass to its dynamodb manager to set it up which means for example we can mock our model as per below test

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetAllData_ShouldGetAll()
{
    var searchResult = new List<MyModel>()
    {
        new MyModel() {FirstName = "abc", LastName="def", Address = "123 street", UpdatedBy = "abc"},
        new MyModel() {FirstName = "ghj", LastName="asd", Address = "56 street", UpdatedBy = "ghj"}
    };
    _dbManager
        .Setup(_ => _.GetAsync(It.Is<List<ScanCondition>>(list => list.Count == 2)))
        .ReturnsAsync(searchResult);


     // Act
     var okResult = _setController.GetAllData().Result as OkObjectResult;

     // Assert
    var items = Assert.IsType<List<MyModel>>(okResult.Value);
    Assert.Equal(2, items.Count);
}
```

As per above test since our model is setup with 2 records, the above test returns true as we are checking items count to be 2.

Ques:
- Is this the correct way to mock?
- Is this the correct way to write the test and check if it returns all data from db.

Now the above is all about mocking. What if I dont want to mock and use actual database to check and run my tests. How can I do that.

I tried setting up my test contructor as below:

```
public class ValuesControllerTests
{
      private ValuesController _valuesController;
      private readonly IDynamoDbManager<MyModel> _dbManager;
      public ValuesControllerTests()
      {

            _dbManager = mockRepository.Create<IDynamoDbManager<MyModel>>();

            _valuesController = new ValuesController(options, _dbManager);      

      } 
}
```

But my _dbManager is always null, I am not sure how to set this up correctly.

My final question:
- Which is a better approach: using moq for testing or using live connection.

Sorry for long post but I wanted to clear out things and follow correct approach.

Anyone for inputs?